# Laravel - File doesnot exist at path

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen other solutions too here in StackOverflow to increase the
`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini` but my problem is it only happens in production not in local. Any solution for this ?? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you have no access to php.ini in production

Comment: Yes and I also cannot recreate the issue in my local.

Comment: Looks like you will have to set those in  `.htaccess` or `.user.ini`